# Loop over variable sized arrays

Tags: syntax, list-manipulation

I would like to build an Encoder/Decoder to export my Data from Mathematica to Julia. From Mathematica I get arrays of variable dimensions, these arrays contain variables that don't have a fixed value by now and therefore cannot be exported by the hdf5 format (as far as I know).

To solve this problem I want to write a simple Encoder which just exports an array of a certain number combination in Mathematica and the Decoder in Julia reinterpret these numbers as variables (the Julia side isn't a problem since I'm familiar with it).

My plan is to define a function which has as input an array of variable dimension and it should output for me the information about the variables stored in its entries.

To be concrete the most to popular ones are of the size {2,2,2,2} and {2,2,2,4,4,2,2,2}. Now I have to search every entry of these arrays for the variables occurring there and write for each variable in there a specific number combination to a separate array (which I can export via the hdf5 format) of the same size. The problem I have is that I don't know the correct command in Mathematica to create a loop that goes through every entry of an array whose size is variable.

Example: Look at the following array
[image]

Look at the first entry. There are the variables `\[Sigma]`,`\[Sigma]^\[Prime]`, `\[Sigma]^\[Prime]\[Prime]` and `a`. I can get a list of all variables contained in this entry by using the `Variables[.]` command. I want to store in a separate array that at position `[[1,1,1,1]]` of this array there are the variables `\[Sigma]`,`\[Sigma]^\[Prime]`, `\[Sigma]^\[Prime]\[Prime]` and `a`. This can be done by writing, for example, the number `1111` (a one for each variable showing up in this expression). Additional to this I also want to store the powers of the variables to another array by writing another number into it.

In the end, I have stored all information about occurring variables and their powers showing up in all of the entries of my original array. The problem I'm stuck on is how I can get my function to work when the Input is not a {2,2,2,2} and for example an array of {2,2,2,4,4,2,2,2}. In other words, I search for a function that goes through all entries of arrays which I put into my function.

Cheers

Comment: I don't get it. Would you please post a concrete example of such an array?

Comment: If I was trying to do this I might start with `Dimensions[array]` to get the dimensions of the array, then pass that rank-1 array to Julia along with the rank-1 output of `Flatten[array]`.  But it's very unclear that this is what you seek, or even close to it !  Perhaps in shooting my guess down in flames you can clarify your question.

Comment: I have updated the question, sry

Comment: @Hamilcar Have you looked into the `Map` function? By using, for example `Map[func, array, Infinity]` you can apply `func` to every level of the array. The exact specification for the level will depend on your situation.

Comment: Thanks the Map function was the solution I searched for.